# Python Regex - concatenating multiple lines based on a criteria

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file and I want to remove all newline characters in between the adjacent lines where both have only 'capital letter' words/characters. So if one line is `ABCD` and the next line is `AB`, the result should be `ABCD AB`. I can do it with looping over the text line by line, but I need a more elegant way preferably with regex. Here is a text example:

```
ABCD  
AB
abcd ABB
cd
AB
ABC
ABCD
ab
```

and I want to get this:

```
ABCD AB
abcd ABB
cd
AB ABC ABCD
ab
```

I've written the following, but only works for two capital lines in a row and not more.

```
r = re.compile(r'(\n)([A-Z ]+)(\n)([A-Z ]+)(\n)')
text = r.sub(r'\1\2 \4\5',text)
```

Assume there are no other complexities than this (the text is clean already as the example is). I am a newbie struggling to learn regex! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/kI8pL4):

Search: `(?m)([A-Z ]+)[\r\n]+(?=[A-Z ]+$)`

Replace: `\1`

1. Note that we are inserting a space where you used to have a newline.

   result = re.sub(r"(?m)([A-Z ]+)[\r\n]+(?=[A-Z ]+$)", r"\1 ", subject)

Comment: Hey Mor, glad it works, but please see my edit with point number 2. :)